# Missing Browse Tab in the Reference Manager dialog box

Tags: visual-c++, visual-studio-2015, gpib

I have been trying to add a local .dll file to my project as I need some built in commands it has for my offline simulation connecting to a GPIB. The problem is I am missing the "Browse" tab to search for the .dll file to add.

[image]